# How can I use libcurl function "curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, char *address);"

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I want to use function `curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, char *address)`, but when I download the source code,

```
./configure && make && make install
```

every fucntion is OK but this function `curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, char *address)`. This function explanation  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.html.AVAILABILITY says this option requires that libcurl was built with a resolver backend that supports this operation. The c-ares backend is the only such one. what does it mean? how I build libcurl with a resoluver backend.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you need to make sure that you build your libcurl to use [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) for name resolving. This is because "normal" name resolver functions can't be told which servers to use (nor which source address to use when doing that communication), they use the ones you set in the system files.

c-ares is a separate library that does asynchronous DNS and name resolver calls that libcurl can be told to use.