# How can I use libcurl to get a page with a specific server IP

Tags: c, curl, web-crawler, libcurl

I am crawling a page by libcurl. I need to use specific IP to get page. this ip has been made by the DNS resolver. So I can skip the `getaddrinfo` in libcurl and cost less time.

I have asked a question [How can I use libcurl function "curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, char *address);"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738520/how-can-i-use-libcurl-function-curl-easy-setoptcurl-handle-curlopt-dns-local/29741044) but I found this is not what I want.

Comment: so you want to access say `http://some.tld/file.ext` and you already know that you want to access `some.tld` using a specific IP, say `123.456.789.1`? did I understand that correctly?

Comment: So why don't you directly access `http://123.456.789.1/file.ext`?

Comment: it is not always right. for example, the website https://example.com the server IP is 93.184.216.34 but I can not get page by https://93.184.216.34

Comment: You may need to add a `Host: example.com` header to the request.

Comment: Adding a Host: HTTP header should do the job, unless the server uses some SNI setup and then CURLOPT_RESOLVE is the only solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "pre-populate" libcurl's DNS cache with [CURLOPT_RESOLVE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html), and then you can keep using the host name in the URL just like normal.

Here's a little sample telling curl example.com is at 127.0.0.1

```
CURL *curl;
struct curl_slist *host = NULL;
host = curl_slist_append(NULL, "example.com:80:127.0.0.1");

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_slist_free_all(host);
```

Another option is to use the correct IP in the URL and send a custom Host: header that includes the correct host name.

([CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.html) sets "the local IPv4 address that the resolver should bind to" and is thus a completely different functionality)

Comment: sorry the port is 443